# не понимаю что с разметкой

Tags: java, android, main

Подскажите новичку пожалуйста, не понимаю в чем дело с разметкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ru.turbopro.mytetris.MainActivity">
<ru.turbopro.mytetris.GameView
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />
       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/SCORE"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/score"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/game"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/game"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />
       <Button
    android:id="@+id/vlevo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/levo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
       <Button
    android:id="@+id/perev"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_105470"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pravo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vlevo" />
       <Button
    android:id="@+id/pravo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_299265"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: там же написано - необходимо использовать тему AppCompat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в стилях (`res/values/styles.xml`) - там у вас некорректный родитель как и указано в сообщении об ошибке.

Вам надо родительской темой указать `Theme.AppCompat.Light` вместо чего-то вроде **Theme.Material**

Comment: @MishaRock, по идее ничего дополнительно подключать не надо. Коли не работает - добавьте код файла со стилями в вопрос. текстом только, не картинкой. И напишите какая именно у вас там ошибка.